# Python: unable to import classes from higher directory

Tags: python, flask, python-import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I am learning flask. I have a directory structure that looks something like this.

```
    project
    - controllers
    -- auth.py
    -- main.py
    - db
    -- setup.py
    - models
    -- models.py
    - templates
    -- base.html
    -- index.html
    -- login.html
    -- signup.html
    -- 404.html
    -__init__.py
```

The file **init**.py looks like this

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

    # init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
    db = SQLAlchemy()


    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)

        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '9OLWxND4o83j4K4iuopO'
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/mission_to_mars'

        db.init_app(app)

        # blueprint for auth routes in our app
        from .controllers.auth import auth as auth_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

        # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
        from .controllers.main import main as main_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

        return app
```

I'm trying to import the db variable and create_app() function in controllers/auth.py, controllers/main.py, models/models.py, db/setup.py

I have tried the below syntaxes

```
    from .. import db, create_app
```

which gives the error:

```
    ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have also tried

```
    from project import db, create_app
```

which gives the error

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

I want to know how I can import classes from different directories so that I can use them further in the project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to have (empty) `__init__.py` files in every sub directory.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer... i tried that. but still getting the same errors

Comment: ... you didn't show them in your directory structure

Comment: @MauriceMeyer... I meant I added them after your comment but still getting the same errors